# How to query multiple Child data against one Master data?

Tags: sql, oracle, parent-child

I want to **SELECT** one parent and all the child under it. What Oracle does is it keeps showing the parents against its child.
Please tell me how to show the following query in **ORACLE** from this:

```
select d.department_name, e.last_name from employees e join departments d
on (d.department_id=e.department_id)
group by d.department_name, e.last_name
order by 1;

DEPARTMENT_NAME                LAST_NAME
------------------------------ ------------
Accounting                     Gietz
Accounting                     Higgins
Executive                      De Haan
Executive                      King
Executive                      Kochhar
-------------------------------------------
```

Like this:

```
DEPARTMENT_NAME                LAST_NAME
------------------------------ ------------
Accounting                     Gietz
                               Higgins
Executive                      De Haan
                               King
                               Kochhar
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That kind of report formatting should be done in the application (GUI). SQL isn't really the right choice for that

Comment: ... because with SQL we merely select data. 'Higgins' belongs to 'Accounting', not to ''. It *is*  possible to do this with SQL (using `LAG` to see whther this is the same department as the previous one), but I agree with a_horse_with_no_name, that you should care about the layout/display in your app or Website instead.

Comment: Why the `GROUP BY` clause, by the way? You are not aggregating anything in your query. Remove it.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `analytical function` as following:

```
Select case when rn = 1 then department_name end as dept
       ,last_name from
(select d.department_name, e.last_name,
       Row_number() over (partition by d.department_name order by e.last_name) as rn
 from employees e join departments d
on (d.department_id=e.department_id)
group by d.department_name, e.last_name)
order by department_name, rn;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks you so much mate!! You are indeed a savior :D

Comment: @tayeen . . . The `order by` does not match the calculation of `rn` so this does not guarantee that the `null`s follow the department name.

Comment: @GordonLinoff : the same departments from the inner query must have the same department_name so it will work when I have added the `RN` in `order by` for guaranteed order. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This type of data transformation is best done at the application layer.  But if you want to do it in SQL, you can use window functions -- but with the caveat that the ordering of the rows is *very* important.  I would suggest:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by d.department_id order by e.last_name) = 1
             then d.department_name
         end) as dept,
       last_name 
from employees e join
     departments d
     on d.department_id = e.department_id
group by d.department_name, e.last_name
order by d.department_name, dept nulls last;
```

I also sincerely doubt that you need the `group by`, unless the tables have duplicates.  So:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by d.department_id order by e.last_name) = 1
             then d.department_name
         end) as dept,
       last_name 
from employees e join
     departments d
     on d.department_id = e.department_id
order by d.department_name, dept nulls last;
```

Comment: You are right. The GROUP BY clause is not needed. Thank you for that!! :D
However your query doesn't produce the desired result. It only shows this department_name at first and then the names of the employees without informing who is under which department.

Comment: @tayeen . . . Fixed.  The `order by` needed two keys, not one.

Comment: Works like a charm now!